# Did Jehu put words in Elijah's mouth in 2 Kings 9:37?

Tags: 1-kings, 2-kings

Elijah prophecied in

> 1 Kings 21:23 “And also concerning Jezebel the Lord says: ‘Dogs will devour Jezebel by the wall of Jezreel.’
> 24“Dogs will eat those belonging to Ahab who die in the city, and the birds will feed on those who die in the country.”

While this prophecy was being fulfilled, Jehu confirmed the above in

> 2 Kings 9:36 They went back and told Jehu, who said, “This is the word of the Lord that he spoke through his servant Elijah the Tishbite: On the plot of ground at Jezreel dogs will devour Jezebel’s flesh. 37 Jezebel’s body will be like **dung** on the ground in the plot at Jezreel, so that no one will be able to say, ‘This is Jezebel.’ ”

Did Jehu put words in Elijah's mouth by the addition of "dung on the ground"?

Answer (score 2):

Jehu's words are an undeniable consequence of what Elijah prophesied.

But we have no record of Elijah saying it.

One might be tempted to suppose that Jehu has - perhaps a little crudely - embellished the prophet's words, but one cannot prove it.